# Window 10 UWP app development

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to convert my windows phone 8.1 app to windows 10 UWP app. I copy pasted my code files directly to windows 10 app solution and now I am getting these errors:
[image]

I need these libraries for my project but they are not supported for windows 10, what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@thewarri0r9 There are options to convert your existing project (either 8.1 WinRT or Silverlight). In this case you you want to convert your WP 8.1 Silverlight project. Please note that even if you use this solution you will have still do some additional changes if needed.

1. Here you can find description how to convert your WP 8.1 Silverlight project to UWP - nice description with images how to do it in the Visual Studio. This is official Channel9 website.

https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Bridging-the-WinPhone-to-UWP-Gap

2. You will have to use "Mobilize.NET’s Silverlight bridge": Here you can download this extension for Visual Studio:

http://www.mobilize.net/download-silverlight-bridge

I hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to start rewriting the app using the new APIs. There is no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

I see , you have your app for Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight that is not compatible almost of the all code for UWP apps you will need to rewrite your app again.